# Django can't migrate when i make models

Tags: django, model, migrate, makemigrations

whenever i try to add a simple model like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.
class Post(models.model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=43)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

i get this error massage when i try to make migrations.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rickdegraaf/venv/projects/blog-tutorials/blog/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/rickdegraaf/venv/projects/blog-tutorials/blog/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 420, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 269, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/rickdegraaf/venv/projects/blog-tutorials/blog/blog1/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    class Post(models.model):
TypeError: function() argument 'code' must be code, not str
```

and i don't know why ?

i tried adding this:

from .models import Post

admin.site.register(Post)

to admin.py
and in setting.py i added my app to it like 'blog1',
by installed apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to capitalize Model.
It should look like this:
`class Post(models.Model):`

**Short explanation:**

You get this error because the class is called Models with a capital M. The model.models is some kind of string inside the model file.

Comment: thank you i just figured it out myself but thanks anyway for the quick reaction :)

Comment: @rickdegraaf no problem, glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

class Post(models.model):

change your code to
class Post(models.Model)